# Xpath for a SOAP request taking namespaces into account

Tags: xml, web-services, xpath, soap

I wonder if someone can help kick me off in requirements for traversing a SOAP response using XPath to pick out data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <ns2:preferredPaymentSearch  xmlns:ns2="http://website.abc.com">
     <header>
        <issueAudit>
           <info>
              <issues>
                 <issue severity="INFO" issueId="7f32d1f1-8355-4af3-8862-6e3b66061c41" host="server.test.com/10.2.333.46" issueMessage="qqdG6jVIqIkw459wSj0ymokh" issueCode="TrackingId" timestamp="2017-03-22T09:36:40.362Z" />
                 <issue severity="INFO" issueId="220f5972-eed0-43e3-be72-cdbea1798520" host="server.test.mcom/10.2.333.46" issueMessage="server.test.com/10.2.333.46" issueCode="Host" timestamp="2017-03-22T09:36:40.362Z" />
              </issues>
           </info>
           <warnings>
              <issues />
           </warnings>
           <errors>
              <issues />
           </errors>
        </issueAudit>
        <status>SUCCESS</status>
        <ver>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</ver>
     </header>
     <results>
        <preferredPaymentResults>
           <preferredPaymentCriterion>
              <productSupplier>
                 <ns2:actorCode>ABC</ns2:actorCode>
              </productSupplier>
              <requiredFunds amount="59.29" currency="GBP" />
           </preferredPaymentCriterion>
           <preferredPaymentOption>
              <preferredCardOption>
                 <cardForm>PHYSICAL</cardForm>
                 <cardType>VISA_CREDIT</cardType>
                 <provider>lodged</provider>
              </preferredCardOption>
           </preferredPaymentOption>
        </preferredPaymentResults>
     </results>
  </ns2:preferredPaymentSearch>
```

How would I obtain the data within the `<status>` tag?

I would have thought the following would return the required "SUCCESS" data:

```
//soap:Body/descendant::*[name()='status']
```

Comment: What's the problem with your XPath? It should've worked : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/db1e368fd8865035f4523a8dd54f0d13

Comment: Or maybe you only need to append `/text()` at the end of that XPath to get the inner text?

Comment: hmmm. perhaps the tool I am using is giving erroneous results: http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester

Comment: Yup, looks like the problem is in the tools you're using. This one worked there though : `//soap:Body//*[name()='status']`

Answer (score 0):

```
//header/status/text()
```

Please try with above xpath,it will give "SUCCESS"